# Como escutar mudanças reativas em dois controles de formulário ao mesmo tempo no angular

Tags: angular, typescript, formulário, programação-reativa

Estou com um pequeno problema no angular.
Ao digitar em um campo de formulário, eu estou inserindo mudanças em outro campo. Porém quando tendo usar em dois formulários ao mesmo tempo o console mostra o seguinte erro:

**core.mjs:6461 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Meu código:

```
ngOnChanges(): void {
      this.createForm();
      this.setProposedPercentage();
      this.setProposedPercentageByNewSalary()  

  }

createForm(): void {
    this.myForm= this.formBuilder.group({
      newSalary: [0],
      currentSalary: [0],
      proposedPercentage: [0],
    });
  }

calculateProposedPercentage(newSalary: number, currentSalary:number): void {
    let value = newSalary - currentSalary;
    let result = (value / currentSalary) *100;
    this.myform.get('proposedPercentage').setValue(result);
  }

  calculateNewSalaryByProposedPercentage(currentSalary:number, proposedPercentage: number,  newSalary: number): void {
    let value = currentSalary * (proposedPercentage/100);
    let result = value + newSalary;
    this.myform.get('newSalary').setValue(result);
  }

  setProposedPercentage(): void {
    merge(
      this.myform.get('newSalary').valueChanges,
    ).pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribeNotifier)).subscribe(
      () => {
        const currentSalary = this.myForm.get('currentSalary').value;
        const newSalary = this.myForm.get('newSalary').value;

        if (currentSalary && newSalary) {
          this.calculateProposedPercentage(newSalary, currentSalary);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  setProposedPercentageByNewSalary(): void {
   merge(
      this.myform.get('proposedPercentage').valueChanges,
    ).pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribeNotifier)).subscribe(
      () => {
        const currentSalary = this.myForm.get('currentSalary').value;
        const newSalary = this.myForm.get('newSalary').value;
        const proposedPercentage = this.myForm.get('proposedPercentage').value;

        if(currentSalary){
          this.calculateNewSalaryByProposedPercentage(currentSalary, proposedPercentage, newSalary)
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Só corrigindo pessoal é em dois controles de formulário ao mesmo tempo e não em dois formulários.

Answer (score -2):

Consegui encontrar uma solução para o problema:

Adicionei o operador distinctUntilChanged() na chamada reativa e adicionei uma propriedade no resultado do formulário:

O código ficou assim:

```
calculateProposedPercentage(newSalary: number, currentSalary:number): void {
    let value = newSalary - currentSalary;
    let result = (value / currentSalary) *100;
    this.myform.get('proposedPercentage').setValue(result, {emitEvent : false});
  }

  calculateNewSalaryByProposedPercentage(currentSalary:number, proposedPercentage: number,  newSalary: number): void {
    let value = currentSalary * (proposedPercentage/100);
    let result = value + newSalary;
    this.myform.get('newSalary').setValue(result, {emitEvent : false});
  }

  setProposedPercentage(): void {
    merge(
      this.myform.get('newSalary').valueChanges,
    ).pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(
      () => {
        const currentSalary = this.myForm.get('currentSalary').value;
        const newSalary = this.myForm.get('newSalary').value;

        if (currentSalary && newSalary) {
          this.calculateProposedPercentage(newSalary, currentSalary);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  setProposedPercentageByNewSalary(): void {
   merge(
      this.myform.get('proposedPercentage').valueChanges,
    ).pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(
      () => {
        const currentSalary = this.myForm.get('currentSalary').value;
        const newSalary = this.myForm.get('newSalary').value;
        const proposedPercentage = this.myForm.get('proposedPercentage').value;

        if(currentSalary){
          this.calculateNewSalaryByProposedPercentage(currentSalary, proposedPercentage, newSalary)
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).